# CentOS 6 - Preventing people from accessing certain files?

Tags: centos, php

So I have my CentOS 6 server, which is nice and good. But for some reason, people can always access my board's files and download them, such as http://mariomansion.net/templates/pagelayout.tpl
If you click that, it'll download the file. I have other files, such as SQL files that I don't want people to download.

How do I prevent people from accessing or downloading the files?

Comment: Are these files *meant* to be available to clients, just not individually downloaded under normal circumstances, or are they purely internal to the software you are using and never referred to from the web browser? If the latter, you may want to investigate placing them outside of your site's publicly accessible root, but exactly what this will entail depends completely on the software you are running.

Comment: It's not supposed to be available to people. It's there, but it shouldn't really be touched by anyone. A 404 when someone is trying to access it would be good.

Comment: Given this is website related, I'm not certain this questions is considered [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic); you might have more luck on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)